# AngularJS ng-show 2 way binding not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am new to AngularJS and I have seen others asking similar questions, but the answers are not working for me. Rather than hijacking those questions, I thought I would open one for myself.

I am creating a demo app -- it lists "sites" which can be added to or deleted. I am using the ng-show attribute to display the required html div while hiding the others.

Here is the back-end javascript--

```js
    var SiteMaintenanceModule = angular.module("SitesMaintenance", []);
    SiteMaintenanceModule.controller("siteCtrl", diveSiteCtrlfn);

    function diveSiteCtrlfn($scope) {
        // initializing the sites array
        $scope.sites = sites;

        //initializing the Divs array
        $scope.allowedDivs = ["listSiteDiv","addSiteDiv", "editSiteDiv","deleteSiteDiv"];
       
        // setting the first div as selected. This should show the div which lists the sites       
        $scope.selectedDiv = $scope.allowedDivs[0];

        // function to be called with the selected div is to be changed
        $scope.setSelectedDiv = function ($divSelectedByUser) {
            $scope.selectedDiv = $divSelectedByUser;
        }
     };
```

And here is the html

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="SitesMaintenance">
<head>
    <title>List of Dive Sites</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="./../zHelpers/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="./../zHelpers/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./sites.js"></script>
    <script src="./SiteMaintenance.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="siteCtrl">

    <!-- Display the list of sites  based on the selectedDiv variable-->
    <div id="SiteList" ng-show="{{selectedDiv == 'listSiteDiv'}}">
        <h3>List of Sites</h3>
        <ul ng-repeat="site in sites" ng-model="sites">
            <li>{{site.site}} in {{site.location}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Display the add site Div  based on the selectedDiv variable-->
    <div id="AddSite" ng-show="{{selectedDiv == 'addSiteDiv'}}">
        <h3>Add New Site</h3>
        <div style="display:block; margin:10px">Site: <input id="inputAddSiteName" /></div>
        <div style="display:block; margin:10px">Location: <input id="inputAddSiteLocation" /></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Display the edit site Div based on the selectedDiv variable -->
    <div id="EditSites" ng-show="{{selectedDiv == 'editSiteDiv'}}" style="display:block;margin:20px">
        Site Name:<input id="InputEditSiteName" />
        Site Location:<input id="InputEditSiteLocation" />
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
        <button id="AddNewSiteButton" ng-click="setSelectedDiv('addSiteDiv')">Add Site</button>
        <button id="DeleteSiteButton" ng-click="setSelectedDiv('deleteSiteDiv')">Delete Site</button>
        <button id="EditSiteButton" ng-click="setSelectedDiv('editSiteDiv')">Edit Site</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

I can set the visible div to whatever I want at the start, by changing the index in the statement "$scope.selectedDiv = $scope.allowedDivs[0];" in the JavaScript.

I change the value of $scope.selectedDiv when any of the buttons on the page are clicked, so as to change the visibility of the divs.

However, the visibility of the divs doesn't change, no matter what the value of $scope.selectedDiv is. In fact, when debugging in chrome, I see that the attribute value of ng-show for each of my divs updates dynamically to "true" or "false" and expected, but the div is still displayed -- the initially invisible divs seems to have a class="ng-hide" attribute, which never changes.

I have tried $scope.$apply() in the JavaScript but that gives errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `{{}}` interpolation inside `ng-show` directive directive, it evaluates the expression inside a `$scope` of your controller directly.

```
ng-show="selectedDiv == 'addSiteDiv'"
ng-show="selectedDiv == 'listSiteDiv'"
ng-show="selectedDiv == 'editSiteDiv'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Did not realize that adding the {{}} could cause issues.

Comment: @Akash np. Glad to help you.. Thanks :)